# Splitting string of pairs of numbers, then splitting each one of them in java

Tags: java, parsing, split

lets say I have the following line:

```
ball_velocities:45,500 46,500 47,500
```

I would like to:

- split the pairs from each other
- split the the pair itself and the numbers inside of it from each other
  use both of those numbers in a function that I already have

> ```
>    String[] numbers = data.split("\\\\s+");
>    if (numbers.length > 0) {
>             List<Velocity> velocities = new ArrayList<>();
>          for (String number : numbers) {
>              try {
>                  int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(number);
>                       int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(number);
>                 velocities.add(Velocity.pair(firstNum,secondNum));
> ```

I know I have messed it up, so I'll be glad to hear some suggestions.

I think it's pretty simple, all I gotta do is to data.split by spaces as I already did
data split again by comma and then I don't know how to combine those 2 numbers into one function.

I mean in the end I want it to be:
a list of velocities that contain the values of:

```
Velocity.pair(45,500)
Velocity.pair(46,500)
Velocity.pair(47,500)
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does a `Velocity` look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the class `Velocity` looks like this:

```
class Velocity {
    private int firstNumber;
    private int secondNumber;

    public Velocity(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        super();
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public int getFirstNumber() {
        return firstNumber;
    }

    public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
    }

    public int getSecondNumber() {
        return secondNumber;
    }

    public void setSecondNumber(int secondNumber) {
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[" + firstNumber + ", " + secondNumber + "]";
    }
}
```

you will basically have to go step by step:

1. remove the introducing tag `ball_velocities:` from the `String` you want to split,
2. `split` the result by an arbitrary amount of whitespaces, then
3. `split` each result of that by comma,
4. parse the results to `int`s
5. instantiate a `Velocity` with the results of the parsing and finally
6. add each instance of `Velocity` to the `List<Velocity>`

which can be done as follows, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String data = "ball_velocities:45,500 46,500 47,500";

    List<Velocity> velocities = new ArrayList<>();
    // remove the intro tag and then split by whitespace(s)
    String[] numberPairs = data.replace("ball_velocities:", "").split("\\s+");

    // handle each result (which still consists of two numbers separated by a comma
    for (String numberPair : numberPairs) {
        // that means, split again, this time by comma
        String[] numbers = numberPair.split(",");
        // parse the results to ints
        int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
        // instantiate a new Velocity with the results and add it to the list
        velocities.add(new Velocity(firstNum, secondNum));
    }

    // print the list using the `toString()` method of Velocity
    velocities.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This example will print

```
[45, 500]
[46, 500]
[47, 500]
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I get an error if I try to input more than one pair: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "500 47"

Comment: @DimaCiun How do those pairs look as `String`?

Comment: ball_velocities:45,500 46,500 47,500

Comment: no quotation marks or periods or something else. just what I wrote here^

Comment: @DimaCiun that's exactly the `String` my example is using... If you don't receive it like that, show me how you *input* the values, please...

Comment: @deHaar you can see my full codes here: https://pastebin.com/Yam8hsdZ, https://pastebin.com/gV2Xruf5

Comment: Your full codes do not contain exact input string. Also, you're splitting like this: data.split("\\\\s+"); which is not correct

Comment: @AlexRudenko the exact input string is mentioned here, twice. Or I'm not getting what you're trying to say by "exact input string". I'm splitting like this because this is already after line.substring: if (line.startsWith(BALL_VELOCITIES)) {
                    setInitialBallVelocities(level, line.substring(BALL_VELOCITIES.length()));

Comment: @DimaCiun, your code: `String[] velocityPairs = data.split("\\\\s+");`
deHaar's code: `data.replace("ball_velocities:", "").split("\\s+");`
my code: `velo.split("\\s+")`
Do you see a difference?

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes. I thought i'm not supposed to add deHaar's part of "data.replace" because I already took care of the "ball_velocities:" part. I'll try your suggestion. Also, how do you think I should take care of the check I want to run. I mean I do want to print all the velocities in this list to check whether it works or not, because they are not in the same class as you saw.

Comment: @DimaCiun, both deHaar's and mine answers provide enough code to print the velocities using `forEach` construct.  Regarding `data.replace` part - _you_ posted the input string with the prefix _here_, that's why the answerers had to remove this prefix by themselves.

Comment: @deHaar attaching for you my codes again because it got deleted from pastebin: https://pastebin.com/fXKnZAse , https://pastebin.com/s9wwhQKJ

Comment: @DimaCiun, are you ok?? What stops you from replacing _your_ **incorrect** regexp `data.split("\\\\s+");` to **correct** one `data.split("\\s+");`??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a string of data with velocity information, you can use the following snippet:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Velocity {
    int id1;
    int id2;

    static Velocity pair(int i1, int i2) {
        return new Velocity(i1, i2);
    }
}
// -------- testing
String input = "ball_velocities:45,500 46,500 47,500";
String velo = input.replaceAll("ball_velocities\\s*\\:\\s*", ""); //remove prefix containing optional whitespaces

// String velo = "45,500 46,500 47,500";

Arrays.stream(velo.split("\\s+"))
      .map(s -> s.split("\\,"))
      .map(a -> Velocity.pair(Integer.parseInt(a[0]), Integer.parseInt(a[1])))
      .collect(Collectors.toList()) // list of velocity is available here
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
Velocity(id1=45, id2=500)
Velocity(id1=46, id2=500)
Velocity(id1=47, id2=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's get the inputs into a `String` array:

```
String[] inputs = data.split(":")[1].split(" ");
```

Essentially we get the right-most part of the colon first and `split` that into an array of `String` items, which represent the input you have, having values like "45,500". Let's create a `Velocity` array and fill it with items:

```
Velocity[] velocities new Velocity[inputs.length];

for (int index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
    String parts = inputs[index].split(",");
    velocities[index] = new Velocity(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```